# Mysql change cell value based on 2 other record's value's

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database looking like this

Table name: person

```
id  name    country father_id     mother_id   HIV
52  bob     NULL    68            98          NULL
68  joe     Maui    72            14          CLEAR
53  mia     NULL    68            98          NULL 
51  robbie  NULL    68            13          NULL
98  Joyce   NULL    13            16          CLEAR
```

I need a query for my database where i update all person.id with HIV 'CLEARED' IF the mother_id and father_id both have HIV CLEAR
please note i need to be able to choose the word i mark the child with, so this will not be the same value as mother_id and father_id.

I need the database to look like this:

```
    id  name    country father_id     mother_id   HIV
    52  bob     NULL    68            98          CLEAR
    68  joe     Maui    72            14          CLEAR
    53  mia     NULL    68            98          CLEAR 
    51  robbie  NULL    68            13          NULL
    98  Joyce   NULL    13            16          CLEAR
```

If this is too complicated, ill stick with using the same value as the parents :P

If the mother_id and father_id are NOT CLEAR i want the person.id HIV cell to stay NULL

Please keep it simple as im a noob at this :P

Comment: show your desired result .

Comment: sorry :P Edited now :)

Comment: your wished result are wrong , you have father_id 68 and he have CLEAR so id 51 should be also CLEAR or ??

Comment: @echo_Me - Both mother AND father need to be clear.  There is no example record for id=13, so id=51 only has One clear parent, not two.  More concerning is that id=13 is id=51's mother and id=98's father...

Comment: no as both the mother and father have to have CLEAR for the child to have clear. but ive got the query from Gordon :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the update statement:

```
update person p join
       person father
       on father.id = p.father_id and father.HIV = 'Clear' join
       person mother
       on mother.id = p.mother_id and mother.HIV = 'Clear'
    set p.HIV = 'ParentsClear';
```

It strikes me that you might only want to do the `update` when the field is empty.  If so, add a `where p.HIV is null` to the query.

EDIT:

I would suggest you revise your table to have a field for `ParentHIV`.  I don't know what you are doing, but there is the danger of getting confused over what is data for the individual and what comes from the parents.

Here is an example for how this might be used:

```
update person p join
       person father
       on father.id = p.father_id and father.HIV = 'Clear' join
       person mother
       on mother.id = p.mother_id and mother.HIV = 'Clear'
    set p.ParentHIV = (case when father.HIV = 'Clear' and mother.HIV = 'Clear'
                            then 'BothClear'
                            when father.HIV = 'Clear' or mother.HIV = 'Clear'
                            then 'OneClear'
                            else 'NeitherClear'
                       end);
```

Comment: but if mother_id have HIV 'cleared' OR 'Clear' and father_id HIV 'cleared' OR 'Clear', how can i get set the p.HIV value? is it as easy as just putting in father.HIV = 'Clear' OR 'Cleared' ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select p.id
From person p
INNER JOIN person father ON father.id = p.father_id 
INNER JOIN person mother ON mother.id = p.mother_id
WHERE father.HIV = 'Clear' AND mother.HIV = 'Clear'
```

Then do an `UPDATE` query with those id's:

```
UPDATE person SET HIV = 'Clear' WHERE id IN (the result set of ids separated by commas)
```

Comment: on the select query: 
Got error #1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: I thought MySQL objected to using the table being updated in the queries used to identify the rows to update.  `UPDATE x SET a = b WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM y)` being okay, but `UPDATE x SET a = b WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM x)` being a problem.  I have also been lead to believe this can be hacked around with an extra level of nesting?  `UPDATE x SET a = b WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM x))`

Comment: @MatBailie Hmm, I'm not sure. I've never done a `SELECT` inside of an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: Ahhh, an answer that hasn't actually been tried and tested ;)

Comment: ok, the select query worked now ive got 2500 ids listed... so how do i update those? :P

Comment: @hichris123 - This fails: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f915d/1  This works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36415

Comment: @CMilla Comma separate the ids and then paste them into the UPDATE query with the `(`'s.

Comment: got the solution from Gordon. Thank you for your time.